# How to configure tor browser in Tails to use meek bridges?

Tags: tails, meek

I noticed the Tor browser that come with Tails live OS is a bit different than Tor browser bundle for Windows OS. The latter comes with built-in sets of bridges(obfs3, obfs4, meek, etc), while in Tails, there're no such options, the configuration window ask you to manually input bridges.

The problem is, obfs3 and obfs4 bridges can be retrieved using bridgeDB, however, there're no meek bridges in bridgeDB. So my question is, is it possible to use meek bridges in Tails? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tails does not currently support `meek` bridges.

There is work being done to enable this, so that `meek` and `moat` will work in the future.

The work is mostly done but it's not yet in place.

The ticket it's being dealt with under is [#8243](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/8243).

Most of the issues revolve around Tails' torification of DNS and meek requiring DNS already in place to work. Since torified DNS can't work until Tor is bootstrapped and Tor can't bootstrap over meek until there's DNS it creates a dependency conflict that needs some work arounds to resolve.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reply. I'll have to make do with TBB bundle for windows now since obfs3/obfs4 bridges don't work in my country anymore.